# new Date() is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have rows with date value as shown below,

```
"/Date(1366009200000)/";
```

I have to sort the rows based on the above date format values and display the result.

I applied a logic to convert this date format and then sort it in descending order. It **works perfect in IE but not in Chrome**.

Here is the code:

```js
var rows = [];

var row1 = {};

    row1.HIREDT = "/Date(1366009200000)/";
rows.push(row1);

var row2 = {};
    row2.HIREDT = "/Date(1362985200000)/";
rows.push(row2);

var latestRow = $.grep(rows, function (row) {                    
                    return Math.max(new Date(row.HIREDT));
                }).sort(function (x, y) {                    
                    return y.HIREDT.localeCompare(x.HIREDT) //desc
                });

$('#result').text('Total rows in result: '+latestRow.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label id="result"></label>
```

**Question:**

`new Date(row.HIREDT)` is working in IE but not in Chrome. Am I missing anything?

Comment: It appears as you are trying to execute the following expression `new Date("/Date(1362985200000)/")`. What do you expect  to get then?

Comment: The fact that IE manages to pick the timestamp from that string is just sheer luck. You'll have to remove all the extra junk from around it manually before you pass it to the date object.

Comment: @c-smile, I am expecting a date from the string "/Date(1362985200000)/".

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601). See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you read [`Date`'s documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)?

> **dateString** String value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the `Date.parse()` method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

You don't have a RFC 2822 or ISO8601 string, so you should expect it to fail.  It only happens to work in IE because

> The ECMAScript specification states: If the String does not conform to the standard format the function may fall back to any implementation–specific heuristics or implementation–specific parsing algorithm. Unrecognizable strings or dates containing illegal element values in ISO formatted strings shall cause `Date.parse()` to return `NaN`.

...in other words, you're getting lucky.

---

If you know that the format of the string you receive will always be the same, just extract the numeric substring.  Since it's already a number (since epoch), you can just `parseInt` and sort directly on the timestamps; no need to involve `Date`.

Comment: make sense. I will try as u suggest.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution

Remove the `/Date(...)/` using substring, and parse it to int before passing to Date's constructor:

```
new Date(parseInt(row.HIREDT.substring(6, row.HIREDT.length - 2)))
```

#### Problem

It seems that [IE does support additional forms of String on Date creation such as a VT_DATE value from an ActiveX Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cd9w2te4(v=vs.94).aspx). But that doesn't mean all browsers will support it.

Since we often need cross browser support, we want a solution that work on all browsers. The most common/standard way known of constructing a Date is by using the time in milliseconds since 1/1/1970, as we can see in [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above suggestions, here is the logic I've implemented and it works in both IE and Chrome...

```
 var latestRow = $.grep(rows, function (row) {
                    var dateString = row.HIREDT.substr(6);
                    var rawDate = new Date(parseInt(dateString));                   
                    return Math.max(rawDate);
                }).sort(function (x, y) {

                    return y.HIREDT.localeCompare(x.HIREDT) //desc
                });
```